# How to deal with generated variables. Cant pass to an expression

Tags: python

So I have this [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/index.html) code:

```
fit_params = Parameters()
for iy, y in enumerate(data):
    fit_params.add( 'mean1_%i' % (iy+1), value=10.0, min=0.0,  max=50.0)
    fit_params.add( 'mean2_%i' % (iy+1), value=40.0, min=0.0,  max=50.0)
    fit_params.add( 'A1_%i' % (iy+1), value=28500.0, min=25000.0, max=33000.0)
    fit_params.add( 'A2_%i' % (iy+1), value=28500.0, min=25000.0, max=33000.0)
    fit_params.add( 'sd1_%i' % (iy+1), value=15.0, min=7.0,  max=23.0)
    fit_params.add( 'sd2_%i' % (iy+1), value=15.0, min=7.0,  max=23.0)
    fit_params.add( 'y0_%i' % (iy+1), value=1000.0, min=300.0, max=1500.0)

for iy in range(2, data_sets+1): 
    #fit_params['mean2_%i' % iy].expr='mean2_1'
    fit_params['sd1_%i' % iy].expr='???'
```

These parameters are generated on the fly. I want to add an expression that for every sd1_n and sd2_n, sd1 < sd2. My variable have

```
...%i' % iy
```

parts, and I have no idea how to deal with them. If variables werent generated, I could just type:

```
    fit_params['sd1_1'].expr='sd1_1<sd2_1'
```

Any help how to deal with generated variables and passing them would be great.
Documentation says nothing about it http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/constraints.html

Comment: Iterate through fit_params till you find a Parameter that matches your criteria then add the expression to it. Matching shouldn't be too hard, looks like you could use a slice for the first three characters- ```key[:3] == 'sd1_'```

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this for your range loop:

```
for p in fit_params:
    if p.startswith("sd1"):
        idx = p.split("_")[1]
        fit_params[p].expr="sd1_{0}<sd2_{0}".format(idx)
```